# How do you access a private field from another class without a getter?

Tags: java, reflection, private-members

is it possible to read private fields using Java reflection?

Comment: Thanks @BahramdunAdil, can please help me how it goes?

Comment: Can you try little google or search on SO itself.

Comment: Yes, look at it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11282279/1196295).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Apcache commons [FieldUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/FieldUtils.html)

```
FieldUtils.readField(object, myfield, true);
```

or else you can use the Reflection as is described and answered in the linked duplicate. So you can set the `setAccessible(true)` before invoking your method.

```
m = object.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(mymethod);
m.setAccessible(true);
m.invoke(object);
```