# How to refer a private method for a Supplier or Consumer in java

Tags: java, java-8, reference

I want to reuse a piece of code written in Private method of another class A. Like

```
class A
{
  private String method(String data){
return "abcd";
}
}

List myList= getListFromSomeSource();
myList.stream()
.map(A::method)
.collect()....etc
```

Comment: You can't use a private method outside of the class it is defined in. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: You can do it with [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11282279/2928853). But it is generally a very bad idea to do so.

Comment: Can you modify anything or add stuff in class A?

Comment: Yes: why is class `A`' being so secretive?  Couldn't `method` be `public` instead of `private`?  Is it really doing anything so intensely private that it can't be shared with the rest of the world?

Comment: @Jrook I am not looking for something like your link. I dont want to create the object, just want to refer the method.
 I cant modify class A. 
- Its in a library. I dont want to rewrite the logic in that method. Just looking for a way to reuse it.

Comment: I guess you have no way. I don't see any problems when we re-write that method.

Comment: @TeaNG I did re-write the method for now. I am looking for a way to reuse the existing method.

Comment: The way you describe it, indeed there doesn’t seem to be any other option than rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to access a `private` method of a class, if the class implementation does not provide such an option and if that implementation cannot be modified, is via reflection.

Assuming that the `method` function of class `A` has a `String` return type, a simple way to do so is

```
public static String invokeMethod(A object, String data) throws Exception {
  Method method = A.class.getDeclaredMethod(“method”, String.class);
  method.setAccessible(true);
  return (String) method.invoke(object, data);
}
```

Since the `Class A` method in question is not static, an object reference would need to be used to access it, with or without reflection, e.g.

```
A object = new A(); // Create object of type A
String data = “...”; // Specify data input
String result = invokeMethod(object, data); // Call method
```

If such an object of type `A` cannot be created, or if the caller does not want to pass to `invokeMethod` a reference to such an object, the only other option left is actually rewriting the `method` function, outside `Class A`.