# TrueCaller Android SDK 'sdkOptions' has private access

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an user login page using TrueCaller SDK.

https://github.com/truecaller/android-full-stack-sdk

At step 6:

```
TrueSdkScope trueScope = new TrueSdkScope.Builder(this, sdkCallback)
   .sdkOptions( TrueSdkScope.SDK_OPTION_WITH_OTP )
   .consentMode(TrueSdkScope.CONSENT_MODE_FULLSCREEN )
   .consentTitleOption( TrueSdkScope.SDK_CONSENT_TITLE_VERIFY )
   .footerType( TrueSdkScope.FOOTER_TYPE_SKIP )
   .build();

TrueSDK.init(trueScope);
```

It throws below error:

```
'sdkOption(int)' has private access in 'com.truecaller.android.sdk.TrueSdkScope.Builder'
```

I want to test `sdkOptions(TrueSdkScope.SDK_OPTION_WITH_OTP)`
but it seems not working for the current setup. How can it be done if anyone has tried?
Or should I try something like:

[How to call a private method from outside a java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282265/how-to-call-a-private-method-from-outside-a-java-class)

Answer (score 0):

This was a closed beta program being run for a new version of the Truecaller SDK. You can get more details and try out this SDK by signing up for the Early access programme [here](https://developer.truecaller.com/auth/eap-201801-dnQpPHCc151oLMYbNIr2K21C/register).